# Firebase_cli_path: missing path to firebase cli tool. Please install firebase in $PATH or specify path

Tags: android, travis-ci, fastlane, firebase-app-distribution

Travis CI throwing the firebase_cli_path. I am not sure how can I specify this path. In Google document, it mentioned that this path will automatically detect. 
Well, then I need to install the firebase tools into Travis CI, How can I do that?

This is travis.yml

```
dist: trusty

branches:
  only:
    - master


before_install:
  - gem install bundler
  - bundle --version
  - bundle install

android:
  components:
    # Uncomment the lines below if you want to
    # use the latest revision of Android SDK Tools
    # - tools
    # - platform-tools

    # The BuildTools version used by your project
    - build-tools-28.0.3

    # The SDK version used to compile your project
    - android-28

    # Additional components
    - extra-google-google_play_services
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - extra-android-m2repository

    # Specify at least one system image,
    # if you need to run emulator(s) during your tests
    - sys-img-x86-android-26
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-17

script:
 - bundle exec fastlane android uatrelease

after_success:
 - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN --non-interactive
```

This is fastfile

```
default_platform(:android)


platform :android do
  desc "Runs all the tests"
  lane :test do
    gradle(task: "test")
  end

  desc "Submit a new Beta Build to Hockey App"
  lane :beta do |options|
    gradle(task: "clean assembleRelease")

    firebase_app_distribution(
                           app: "1:***********************",
                           testers: "abc@gmail.com",
                           release_notes: "Configuring Fastlane",
                           firebase_cli_token:ENV["FIREBASE_TOKEN"]
                       )

end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out it and it's working now. Just included the script to install the standalone firebase tool in Travis. 
[Check this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools#installation) and add this

> curl -sL firebase.tools | bash

in your travis.yml file.

Sample travis.yml

```
dist: trusty

branches:
  only:
    - master


before_install:
  - gem install bundler
  - bundle --version
  - bundle install

before_script:
  - curl -sL firebase.tools | bash

android:
  components:
    # Uncomment the lines below if you want to
    # use the latest revision of Android SDK Tools
    # - tools
    # - platform-tools

    # The BuildTools version used by your project
    - build-tools-28.0.3

    # The SDK version used to compile your project
    - android-28

    # Additional components
    - extra-google-google_play_services
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - extra-android-m2repository

    # Specify at least one system image,
    # if you need to run emulator(s) during your tests
    - sys-img-x86-android-26
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-17

script:
 - bundle exec fastlane “your action”
```